# How do I gracefully update boost which have been got via NuGet in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, nuget, visual-studio-2019

[image]

I get boost library from Manage NuGet Packages in Visual Studio 2019.

[image]

There are several versions in the packages folder. I have deleted several, left the latest. However, when I rebuild a project, the old one `boost.1.71.0.0` would come up again.

I tried to modify MyProject\packages.config and MyProject\MyProject.vcxproj files. Replaced all `boost.1.71` with `boost.1.77`,

[image]

[image]

It still doesn't work. `boost.1.71.0.0` persist coming up.

Comment: It is picking cached version. Try to clean nuget cache.

Comment: If you right click the solution itself, in Solution Explorer, and select Manage NuGet Packages, then go to the installed tab and select the boost package, on the right hand side you'll see a list of projects and what version of the package is installed in each. That's an easy way to find out which project is using a different version to the others.

Answer (score 1):

@zvikan's comment is correct, I succesfully updated my boost version.

[image]

```
Removed package 'boost.1.71.0' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'boost.1.71.0' from MFCTest
Removed package 'boost_date_time-vc142.1.71.0' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'boost_date_time-vc142.1.71.0' from MFCTest
```

[image]

`boost.1.71` disappeared automatically in the packages folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this method.The problem is caused by the cache, you need to clear the cache. Before that, you need to make a backup of the folder where the nuget package is stored in the project folder and delete it (if it exists). I suggest you try Tools> NuGet Package Manager> Package Manager Settings> click Clear All NuGet Cache(s), then restore packages (right click solution node> Restore NuGet Packages). And I suggest you read this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) carefully and run dotnet nuget locals all --clear or nuget locals all -clear to clear the nuget cache completely.
[image]
[image]

Comment: The question author already said they deleted the folder several times, but NuGet kept re-creating it. I don't understand how you believe deleting more folders/files will prevent that from happening again. NuGet restores what packages are configured in projects, so unless that changes, deleting files will just cause them to re-appear at the next restore.

Comment: I think it's a workable way to clean the packages cache in the system drive, for me it's `C:\Users\MyName\.nuget\packages`

Comment: The question is about a solution packages folder, when a project in the solution uses packages.config (Boost is a C++ package, and C++ projects only officially support packages.config, not PackageReference). What you call the "packages cache" is known in NuGet as the global packages folder, which is different. Furthermore, the customer was asking how to stop it from coming back. Clearing the folder doesn't stop it from coming back until the project that references the old package version is upgraded.